# Откуда то берется мусор

Tags: c++

Записываю в двумерный массив char из файла строки:

```
a_words = new char*[v_counter_b];
for (int i = 0; i < v_counter_b; i++){
    a_words[i] = new char[v_maxlen_b];
}

file.seekg(0, file.beg);

for (int n = 0; n < v_counter_b + 1 && !file.eof(); ++n)
    file.getline(a_words[n], 1024);
```

В файле у меня записано :

```
logic
develop
programm
compile
read
write
memory
diagnostic
system
subject
code
purification
sound
perfect
scream
body
keyboard
dashboard
table
list
array
```

А вот что выдает программа:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ээээ... А где у вас двумерный массив? Покажите типы переменных.

Comment: Окей, а чему равно `v_maxlen_b`?

Comment: @VladD самой макс длине слова

Comment: То есть в вашем случае 12?

Comment: Перед считыванием в массив я сосканил макс длину другим циклом и да в данном случае 12

Comment: А нужно 13, вы забыли место под финальный `\0` :) Вот если бы не пользовались низкоуровневыми сишными структурами данных, а перешли на `std::string` и `std::vector`, вам не пришлось бы это держать в голове.

Comment: (И предыдущий цикл не нужен был бы тоже.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В этом цикле

```
for (int n = 0; n < v_counter_b + 1 && !file.eof(); ++n)
    file.getline(a_words[n], 1024);
```

происходит попытка обратиться за пределы выделенной памяти, когда `n` равно `v_counter_b`, так как диапазон допустимых индексов `[0, v_counter_b -1]` для массива `a_words`.

Кроме того состояние конца файла происходит при чтении записи, а проверка только внутри управляющего предложения цикла. Это может привести к тому, что последняя запись массива может иметь неопределенное значение.

Правильно было бы записать этот цикл следующим образом

```
int n = 0;

while ( n < v_counter_b && file.getline(a_words[n], v_maxlen_b) ) ++n;
```

В этом случае переменная `n` содержала бы реальное число прочитанных записей.

Comment: Кажется, у вас где-то был ответ, который объяснял, почему не стоит пользоваться `file.eof()` в условии цикла.

Comment: Но ведь мусор выводится вместо 4го слова, а не вместо последнего...

Comment: @Qwertiy  Программа имеет неопределенное поведение.:)

Comment: На тот момент не имеет.

Comment: @Qwertiy: Имеет, UB имеет право на машину времени. Сейчас найду пруф.

Comment: @Qwertiy На какой на тот? Это показан вывод результата. А куда она запишет данные неизвестно.

Comment: @Qwertiy: Вот: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2014/06/27/10537746.aspx

Comment: А, да. Не учёл, что он не сразу выводит данные при чтении, а сначала всё сохраняет, а потом всё выводит.

Comment: Под "на тот момент" имелось в виду, что UB зависит от пользовательского ввода и пока ввод соответствующих данных не произошёл, UB быть не может.

Comment: @Qwertiy: В примере по ссылке очень похожая штука и рассматривается. Там тоже рассматривается зависимость от пользовательского ввода.

Comment: Хотя конечно выглядит странно, да.

Comment: @VladD, здесь не то. Пока некорректный ввод не случится, всё должно быть хорошо. Но я не заметил, что сначала идёт весь ввод, а потом весь вывод.

Comment: @Qwertiy: Вроде бы это неверно. Цитата: «However, if any such execution contains an undefined operation, this International Standard places no requirement on the implementation executing that program with that input (not even with regard to operations preceding the first undefined operation).»

Comment: То есть, компилятор не прибежит перекомпилировать код _после_ того, как реально случится UB.

Comment: @VladD, там говорится, что если есть неопределённое поведение, то не гарантируется ничего, в том числе то, что будет до ввода. Но ведь если именно ввод вызывает неопределённое поведение, то компилятор об этом не знает, поэтому код до этого не может быть повреждён. Представь, пользователь вводит некое число, а мы его используем как указатель в памяти и что-то по нему пишем. Предположим, пользователь ввёл 0. Но ведь компилятор не мог этого знать, т. е. до этой точки всё выполнялось без UB. А вот после уже может быть что угодно, т. к. там начинается использование 0 в качестве ненулевого указателя

Comment: @VladD, компилятор не имеет право влиять на порядок наблюдаемых эффектов. Во всех языках так. Под точкой имелся в виду момент выполнения, а не строка кода.

Comment: @VladD, я не спорю. Я говорю, что не учёл, что весь вывод идёт после. Если бы было "читаем строку - выводим строку - читаем следующую" (как я подумал сначала), то до чтения с переполнением всё должно было бы быть хорошо.

Comment: @Qwertiy: А, значит я просто не понял смысл вашего комментария, сорри. Удалю тогда лишний флейм.

Answer (score 3):

Пользуйтесь высокоуровневыми структурами данных!

```
std::vector<std::string> a_words;
std::string s;
while (std::getline(file, s))
    a_words.push_back(s);
v_counter_b = a_words.size();
```